# Does Parallel still allow booting from a Bootcamp partition with HIgh Sierra?

Tags: bootcamp, parallels-desktop, high-sierra

Will I be able to create a Bootcamp partition that I can boot into from Parallels once I've upgraded to High Sierra?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but there are a few issues. See [Known issues with macOS 10.13 High Sierra and Parallels Desktop for Mac](https://kb.parallels.com/en/123840):

> **Known issues**
>
> - Cannot create a new Boot Camp VM.   ***Fixed in version 13.1.0***
> - Cannot start an existing Boot Camp VM. ***Fixed in version 13.1.0***
> - Cannot install macOS High Sierra to a virtual machine with Apple File System type.  ***Fixed in version 13.1.0***
> - Cannot install Kaspersky Internet Security for Mac on macOS 10.13 High Sierra.  ***No workaround.***
> - Video artefacts when switching desktop spaces in Full Screen mode.  ***No workaround.***
> - A VM installed from Mac Recovery partition cannot upgrade to macOS High Sierra. ***No workaround.***
> - Parallels Tools system extensions are blocked in macOS High Sierra VM.  ***In macOS High Sierra VM open System Preferences > Security &
>     Privacy > General > click 'Allow'. See [KB 124244](http://kb.parallels.com/en/124244)***
> - Cannot deploy Parallels Desktop to Macs with macOS High Sierra (host OS).   ***See [KB 124289](http://kb.parallels.com/en/124289)***

Comment: Huh. I'm on Parallels 12 and don't have any issues creating new Boot Camp VMs or starting existing ones, on both High Sierra and Mojave.